# Prevent closing of entire Xcode window on Command-W when "Quick Open" menu is open

Tags: keyboard, xcode

I have an Xcode window open with many tabs. I want to open a file through Quick Open (<kbd>⇧⌘O</kbd>).

When I decide to close the Quick Open menu and also close the current tab that I'm on, I'll press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the Quick Open menu, and then press <kbd>⌘W</kbd> to close the tab. However, sometimes I make a mistake and press <kbd>⌘W</kbd> on the Quick Open menu, which causes the entire Xcode window to close instead.

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour? Maybe prevent <kbd>⌘W</kbd> from doing anything when Quick Open is open?

Comment: Oh yes, this is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is solved with Xcode 11! <kbd>⌘W</kbd> doesn't do anything when Quick Open is active now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you unset the keyboard binding for `Close Tab` aka `⌘`+`W`.

1. From Settings.app -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts tap the `+` button
2. From `Application` dropdown select `Xcode`
3. Enter `Close Tab` for the `Menu Title`
4. set any keyboard shortcut you like

[image]

This un-maps `⌘`+`W` shortcut in Xcode app completely. After this you are free to remap the `⌘`+`W` key bindings in Xcode.

In my case I like `⌘`+`W` to close the document so from Xcode -> Preference -> Key Bindings I have these changes (In your case you can bind `Ctrl` + `⌘`+`W` to `Close Tab` instead and leave `Close Document` unmapped).

[image]

Comment: If I understand the answer correctly, this means you're suggesting I use Ctrl+Command+W to close my Xcode tabs from now on?

Comment: Yes, or you can map it to any key combination you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to change the default <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> behaviour in Xcode so that it doesn't close the entire Xcode window.

You can do this via **Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings**.

It may be worth exploring all of the options there. One safe way to do that would be to create a duplicate of the Default Key Bindings set and modify that. More specifically:

1. Launch Xcode
2. Go to **Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings**
3. Click on the Key Bindings Set drop-down menu and select Manage Key Bindings...
4. Now click on the plus (+) option at bottom left of the window
5. Select the Duplicate "Default" option
6. Give the set a name and click <kbd>Done</kbd>
7. Now change the keyboard shortcuts you want and test whether you can get things to work as you'd like

Once you're happy you can exit Xcode preferences. This approach is safe because you can always return to your Default set whenever you want.

Comment: It's a good first place to look, but I don't think it has what I'm looking for. ⌘W's default behaviour is bound to "Close Tab" and not "Close Window", and Xcode prevents deleting the shortcut altogether and shows a message "Can't delete the keyboard shortcut because Close Window has alternate menu items".